# Laravel eloquent query (one to one)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables, `tracks` and `echonestrecords`. Tracks have one record in the `echonestrecords` table with information about the track.

`tracks` has these columns:
`id`, `title`, `artist`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

`echonestrecords` has these columns:
`id`, `track_id`, `tempo`, `mode`, `key`

The `track` object has the `hasOne()`-function to return the `echonestrecord`.
The `echonestrecord` object has the `belongsTo()`-function to return the track.

I want to make an Eloquent-query to get all tracks which have an empty row in the `echonestrecords`-table. That is, a row there the `tempo` is null.

I can do it like this with the raw query, which doesn't return Track objects.

```
$tracks = DB::table('tracks')
    ->select('tracks.*')
    ->join('echonestrecords','echonestrecords.track_id','=','tracks.id')
    ->where('echonestrecords.tempo',null,'NULL')
    ->get();
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with Eloquent. I figured it must be something like:

```
$tracks = (array('echonestrecord' => function($query) {
    $query->where('tempo', null, 'NULL');
}))->get();
```

But this returns all tracks! I'm confused.

Can you help me?

Comment: I have used a long time to read in them, but haven't found the answer.

Comment: can you show your models pls

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Yahooo..

The answer was using whereHas:

```
    $tracks = Track::whereHas('EchoNestRecord', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereNull('tempo');

    })->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is to create a relation and filter it a little bit more:

```
class EchoNestRecord extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'echonestrecords';

}

class Track extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tracks';

    public function RecordsWithNoTempo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('EchoNestRecord')->whereNull('tempo');
    }

}
```

Then you should be able to:

```
$track = Track::find(1);

foreach($track->recordsWithNoTempo as $record)
{
    echo $record->name;
}
```

Use

```
 dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

To check the generated query.

Comment: I tried it, but it $record->name (or $record in general) is null. (Also: I changed 'whereIsNull' to 'whereNull')

Comment: I with I could write a scope in Tracks, like:
    `public function scopeNoEchoNestRecord($query) {
        return $query->hasOne('EchoNestRecord')->whereNull('song_id');
    }`

Comment: Then I could do the query like `$tracks = Track::noEchoNestRecord()->paginate(3);`

Comment: What query do you get in return? Edited to show how to get it.